# Why ActionBarSherlock tabs with fragments example uses tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am new to ABS(ActionBarSherlock) and sometimes ABS seems to be very complicated to me. The whole point(or most of it) of ABS seemed to me to enable older androids(<11)to run actionbar.

I needed to use fragments inside Actionbar tabs so i tried learning from "FragmentTabs.java" which is located inside fragments demo but suprisingly i find out that this example does not use ABS Actionbar and uses tabhost.

my questions are:

> 1. Why rather than ABS actionbar, tabhost is  implemented,while the whole point of ABS is usage of Actionbar? Is it incompatible with fragment's usage?
> 2. Because fragments are defined as static in this example so how can i get a reference to a non-static tabhost and setCurrentTab()? findViewById()
>    won't work because fragments are defined as static
>
> 3.How to switch between tabs based on code logic?The following code will never work.getParent() works neither.

```
          TabHost tabHost =  (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
          tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Here is the code extracted from Sherlock fragment demo:

```
public class FragmentTabs extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
TabHost mTabHost;
TabManager mTabManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); // Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

/**
 * This is a helper class that implements a generic mechanism for
 * associating fragments with the tabs in a tab host. It relies on a trick.
 * Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or Intent that
 * each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching between
 * fragments. So instead we make the content part of the tab host 0dp high
 * (it is not shown) and the TabManager supplies its own dummy view to show
 * as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes care of
 * switch to the correct fragment shown in a separate content area whenever
 * the selected tab changes.
 */
public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final int mContainerId;
    private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> mTabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    TabInfo mLastTab;

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
            int containerId) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mContainerId = containerId;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        mTabs.put(tag, info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }
}
}


public class FragmentStackSupport extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
int mStackLevel = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);

    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFragmentToStack();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
        Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
    } else {
        mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
}


void addFragmentToStack() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // Instantiate a new fragment.
    Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

    // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
    // on to the back stack.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}



public static class CountingFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {
        CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
        return v;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: For your second question "fragments are defined as static" that is not a case all time, your can also define fragments as no static.

Comment: @AndroidCoder You should never create non-static fragments since it prevents them from being recreated by the framework.

Comment: @ Jake Wharton very thoughtful comment but the problem is they did so in the example and they hardcoded the tabs implementation so if i remove static notions,the application stops working.will update my qs to reflect what they did in tabs and fragments.pls notice static notions

Comment: @JakeWharton i am trying to emulate the same in my app and for some reason the tabs are not being populated i have posted the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761581/android-tabhost-inside-fragmentactivity